# jQuery val() returns undefined, prepend() doesn't append in jQuery style and can't change text input size

Tags: jquery, html

I have a bunch of problems, maybe they're caused by the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
        <h2>Aufgaben:</h2>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <ul id="exercise-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li id="addExercise">Aufgabenname: <input type="text" name="aufgabenname" id="aufgabenname" size="20" maxlength="20"></input> Maximalpunktzahl: <input type="text" name="maxPunkte" id="maxPunkte" size="2" maxlength="2"></input><div style="float:right;"><button id="add" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext"></button></div></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            $("#add").on("click", function() {
                var aufgabenname = $("aufgabenname").val();
                var maxPunkte = $("maxPunkte").val();
                $("#addExercise").prepend("<li>Aufgabe: "+aufgabenname+", Maximalpunktzahl: "+maxPunkte+" <div style=\"float:right;\"><button class=\"delete\" data-icon=\"delete\" data-iconpos=\"notext\"></button></div></li>");
            });
        </script>
```

I can create a new `<li>`, but `aufgabenname` and `maxPunkte` are undefined. Furthermore, the `<li>` element doesn't show off in jQuery style, in particular the button is not what it is expected to be. And the text input size is at full length, no matter what I put in the `size` attribute.

Comment: What do you means by <li> element doesn't show off in jQuery style? Can you elaborate

Comment: I added some list items to show you the difference: [Screenshot](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3510/9may6lhf_jpg.htm)

Comment: you're prepending an li TO an li, shouldn't you be inserting it `before` or `after` it instead?

Comment: what is the jQuery function for that?

Comment: `before` or `after` maybe?

Comment: `.insertBefore()` worked. But now I have still the problem with the style. [Screenshot](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3510/6zlusuga_jpg.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#` to target `id`. Change from:

```
var aufgabenname = $("aufgabenname").val();
var maxPunkte = $("maxPunkte").val();
```

to:

```
var aufgabenname = $("#aufgabenname").val();
var maxPunkte = $("#maxPunkte").val();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTL3r/)**

Answer (score 0):

May Issue: You need to call jquery functionality after `ready event fired` from JQuery.
size and maxlength it works as we expected.maxlength how many char user can type and Size determine visible width, in characters.

```
       <h2>Aufgaben:</h2>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <ul id="exercise-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li id="addExercise">Aufgabenname: <input type="text" name="aufgabenname" id="aufgabenname" size="20" maxlength="20"></input> Maximalpunktzahl: <input type="text" name="maxPunkte" id="maxPunkte" size="2" maxlength="2"></input><div style="float:right;"><button id="add" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext"></button></div></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#add").on("click", function() {
                var aufgabenname = $("#aufgabenname").val();
                var maxPunkte = $("#maxPunkte").val();
                $("#addExercise").prepend("<li>Aufgabe: "+aufgabenname+", Maximalpunktzahl: "+maxPunkte+" <div style=\"float:right;\"><button class=\"delete\" data-icon=\"delete\" data-iconpos=\"notext\"></button></div></li>");
            });
});

        </script>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehyZL/)

Comment: This doesn't change neither of the other two problems

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {}); wrapper added and Id selector used.

Comment: document.ready isn't always needed, and in this case it isn't.

Comment: @Kevin B you are right but user might declared jquery.js at bottom of body tag.

Comment: @RajaJaganathan that doesn't matter either. If he did that, `$` would be undefined anyway until after that line, and after that line you wouldn't need to wait for the dom to be ready to interact with it (because you can be 100% certain that it is in fact ready at that point.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var maxPunkte = $(#"maxPunkte").val();
```

there is one problem;

```
var maxPunkte = $("#maxPunkte").val();
```